# Replace every <br /> ont the string with a space not working in edit grdiview in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, gridview

i've stored in database this string

```
mystreet mycity mytown
```

when editing the row in griview i've got string like this in **TextBox**

```
mystreet<br />mycity<br />mytown
```

What i want to do is replace `<br />` with an `space`

I've tried in database with:

```
REPLACE(mystring,'\r' OR '\n' OR '\r\n', ' ')
```

I've tried in *code-behind* with:

```
string newTextcontents = txtcontents.Text.ToString().Replace("'", "`").Replace("<br />", " ");
```

or

```
string newTextcontents = txtcontents.Text.ToString().Replace("'", "`");

string result = Regex.Replace(newTextcontents, @"(?<=\<br \/\>)\s+",
    match => string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("&nbsp;", match.Length)));
```

or in *markup code*

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txcontents" runat="server"
        Text='<%# Server.HtmlDecode(Eval("contents").ToString().Replace("<br />", " ")) %>'
        TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

But that is not working.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: are you use aspx?

Comment: @Julián yes use aspx

Comment: Have you tried replacing the `<br>` tags from the `RowDataBound` event?

Comment: @Julián thanks a lot for suggestion, now the replace working in `RowDataBound`

Comment: Do you mean that your question has been resolved? Or have you already tried that solution?

Comment: @Julián Resolved, thank you